# generating a html image elements in cakephp

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

When I browse "localhost/ProjectName/users" then I get a user account image like

[image]

But When I browse "localhost/ProjectName/users/add" then I get a user account image like

[image]

But I wanna see correct image all actions.

My code is below.

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img src="img/penguen.jpg" class="user-image">
    <?php $this->User = ClassRegistry::init('User');?>
    <span class="hidden-xs">
        <?php if (AuthComponent::user('id')): ?>
        <?= AuthComponent::user('username') ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: is your `img` folder in your `users` folder like this `localhost/ProjectName/users/img/`?

Comment: app/webroot/img/imagename This is my image link

Comment: the path you provided in your comment has nothing in common with the path you have in your question!

Comment: ProjectName/app/webroot/img/imagename

Comment: So if you browse `localhost/ProjectName/app/webroot/img/imagename` in your browser, you will see the image?

Comment: This code is written in" defalut.ctp" file  So that I can see the image all actions like ...users/add or users/edit or users/index. I can see the image when I use only controller name "localhost/ProjectName/users". Here's my controller name is "users". 
when I add a new user then I can't see image.

Comment: And when you can not see the image and the link is broken, what you have for the image `src` in `view source` window of your browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="img/penguen.jpg" class="user-image">
```

was your mistake.

Leverage the helper to generate "valid" links for you, problem solved:

```
$this->Html->image('penguen.jpg', ['class' => 'user-image']);
```

Never use manual a or img tags with manually built URLs, that can only go wrong.